# Usage of *Could have* Fact vs Possibility?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I read this sentence in a Youtube video that explains the meaning of **even if**.

> She could have paid more, but she'd got the same service.

with **even if**:

> Even if she had paid more, she'd have got the same service.

It appears from the example that "could have" indicates a real event that actually took place in the past - not merely a possibility. (the woman had actually paid more).

Yet it is very confusing when "could have" indicates a possibility like in

> "You could have completed it sooner."

So how could we know the real meaning of "could have" in both cases ? For Example:

> Simon could have told her.

Did Simon tell her or not ?

Source: [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2zbq0V6DfE&t=604s) 
Minute 9:50

Thank you

Comment: could you please provide a link to the video?

Comment: [see this description of 'could have'](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/could-have-done-something) - it can have two meanings, and in your case, if they used "even if" as a substitute, it must be meaning 1 (counterfactual: "even though it did not happen")

Comment: @CowperKettle , I have made an edit.

Comment: Thank you for  the link. After seeing the link , it seems I have misunderstood the meaning of Even if , I thought  the sentence in the video meant something actually happened in the past not just a possibility or speculation.

Comment: I would not use the contraction "she'd" in your examples, as it might be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She **could have paid** more, but she'd got the same service.

In this sentence, "could have paid" indicates that she had that possibility in the past but did not use that possibility.

You are right, **could have** + verb is an ambiguous construction, and we rely on context to derive its true meaning.

[From the Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/could-have-done-something):

1. used for saying that something was possible in the past, even though it did not happen
   *You could have been killed.

   I could have told you, but I didn’t think you would listen.

   She could have married Gerald if she’d wanted to.*
2. used for saying that perhaps something was true, although you do not really know
   *The explosion could have been caused by a gas leak.

   It could have been Dan, but I’m not sure.*

---

Related:

- [Another question discussing the ambiguity of 'could have'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27350/2127)