# How to express the past tense

Tags: past-tense

I have just watch movie in which I think that they should built the digestive system of that toy , after watching the movie how can I express that sentence like I express it as

```
They should have made intelligent digestive system of Rand
```

Which Past tense this is and am I expressing it right ?

Comment: This is confusing because you use two different phrases to say the same thing; one in your question and another in the highlighted part. It is also difficult to understand exactly what you want to know.

Comment: I want to know that what I said in highlight part is right to say after movie , because watching movie become my past and now I want to express the opinion which should be done in the movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange example, but assuming OP knows what he means by "intelligent digestive system", and thinks the movie would have been better if "Rand" had one, the correct syntax would be...

> *They should have made **an** intelligent digestive system **for** Rand*

...or perhaps more idiomatically,...

> *They should have **given Rand an** intelligent digestive system*

In the context of fictional characters in books/movies, the author/director effectively plays a god-like role, so he can *give* attributes to characters as he sees fit. Using *make* more strongly implies the "Creator" deciding and explaining in detail to the audience exactly how the "intelligent digestive system" works, which wouldn't always be considered necessary.

---

You could call *should have [done something]* a [past irrealis conditional](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24463/tense-agreement-in-the-past-irrealis-conditionals) construction. In [this link](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/25864328/Conditional-in-English-Language), it's called a "past conditional affirmative" (as opposed to "past conditional negative" *you **shouldn't** have done that*).

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying in your highlighted part is somewhat correct but it's not past tense.
If you want to say that in past tense, it would be something like this..

"They had made an intelligent digestive system." - It's past perfect tense...

Comment: no they didn't made , I want them IF they made it , that thing make more interest in the movie

Comment: @Wish_2_fly: So, you are saying that you want it to say it as a possibility that they had made this system, right??

Comment: exactly , Its like my wish

Comment: In that case, you cannot say it exactly.
All you can do is you can show the assumption that something like that built in past.

Like this, "They could have made an intelligent digestive machine"

Comment: something like that should be build with that robot in the movie

Comment: If your opinion is like this: "I wanted them to do (a)", and the reality is "They **didn't** do (a)", then you can express yourself like in your example: "They should have + past participle".