# Possessive pronouns question

Tags: pronouns

Can someone tell me if **your dad and my** is correct in the following question?

> Today would have been **your dad and my** 40th wedding anniversary.

Thanks much.

CG

Comment: Who is "my"? And please do not use all caps. use the * sign (asterisk) twice to make it bold text. If a mother is speaking: Today, would have been our anniversary. If a mother addresses a child: Today, would have been your dad's and my anniversary. Colloquial.

Comment: What's the idea of using "would have been"?

Comment: @Rompey - Presumably it isn't, for whatever reason (maybe they're divorced or something).

Comment: @Rompey It indicates impossibility of that happening. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26381/3395).

Answer (score 1):

A mother addressing a son or daughter, colloquially:

- Today, would have been our 40th anniversary. [another way, formal or informal]
- Today, would have been your dad's and my 40th anniversary. [informal, mother to child]

The word anniversary after dad's is implied. It may be omitted. It is usual to put the other person first. It's considered less "self-centered".

Answer (score 0):

It simply doesn't sound like you're talking about your and your dad's 40th anniversary (notice the apostrophe-s thing at the end of *dad*), but about two different things: your dad and your 40th anniversary. To better understand why, let's split the sentence up into two separate clauses connected with an *and*:

> Today would have been **your dad** and today would have been **my 40th wedding anniversary**.

First of all, can you see that the statement *today would have been your dad* talks about just your dad and not about your dad's 40th wedding anniversary? Secondly, do you really think that this statement is even making any realistic sense? I don't think so. We need to add the possessive *s* and *40th wedding anniversary* after *your dad* if we want to turn it into something that actually makes sense:

> Today would have been **your dad's 40th wedding anniversary** and today would have been **my 40th wedding anniversary**.

Now, it's all down to just smoothing it all back together into one sentence as before (I think *my* coming before *your dad's* sounds better):

> Today would have been **my and your dad's** 40th wedding anniversary.

Comment: "My and your dad's 40th wedding anniversary" may be interpreted as "our dad's 40th wedding anniversary", don't you agree?

Comment: Technically speaking yes. I'm not sure if it's at all possible to escape this ambiguity completely. But in a context, it would be perfectly clear what is meant.

Comment: The matter is that there's no context to the question as it is put.