# Would be or Would have been?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

1. If I had gone to the party yesterday, I would be very tired today.
2. If I had gone to the party yesterday, I would have been very tired today.

Witch one is correct? 1 or 2?

Comment: 2 = correct.  Search for info on the third conditional, which refers exclusively to the outcome of imaginary past events, rather than present facts or the imaginary future.

Comment: I disagree. So far as I'm concerned they're both syntactically and idiomatically valid, BUT if spoken during the afternoon, only the Perfect version (#2) would be valid with, for example, *If I had gone to the party yesterday, I would **have been** very tired **this morning**.*

Comment: See also [Tense agreement in the past irrealis conditionals](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24463/). Specifically the top answer there, citing Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage* (the "gold standard" in such matters, imho)... *We **sometimes** use structures with **would have ...** to talk about **present and future** situations which are no longer possible because of the way things have turned out.*